# angularjs dragdrop : filter in ng-repeat can't change the index

Tags: angularjs, angular-dragdrop

My source is in the plunker ([click](http://plnkr.co/edit/3iFSPPlRXEJDQTZUGQjg?p=preview))

If I try input the keyword 'sa' in the input box and then you move the Samsung Galaxy S to the below list(target), the item moved is not that, but "iPhone" .

I tried solving this problem for 3 hours. It's very simple code. But I am a newbie in angular js, especially in angular-js-dragdrop. But I know how to solve this problem. But I can't how to solve this.  The prbolem is the filter I used  for quick search like the followings.

```
ng-repeat='item in users | filter:q'
```

So, wihtout filter in ng-repeat, it worked well. But, If I use this in ng-repeat, the problem is that I can't move the item that I drag. The dropped item in the target list is other one. The reason, I guess, the filter didn't change index of the changed after it is filtered.  How can I solve this? Please I am looking forward to receive your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have edited your [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hccqPXEVc1EfuJ4Nr85j?p=preview) to fix it. 
In your options attributes to set index of dragged element do as follows:

```
jqyoui-draggable="{index: users.indexOf(item) ,animate: true}"
```

Comment: Thanks very very much. It is very simple answer. I feel the futility about it. Because I spent past 5 hours today. :)